# Data modeling Issue for Moqui custom application

Tags: moqui

We are working on one custom project management application on top of Moqui framework. Our requirement is, we need to inform any changes in ticket to the developers associated with the project through email.

Currently we are using **WorkEffortParty** entity to store all parties associated with the project and then **PartyContactMech** entity to store their email addresses. Here we need to iterate through WorkEffortParty and PartyContactMech everytime to fetch all email address to which we need to send emails for changes in tickets every time.

To avoid these iterations, we are now thinking of giving feature to add comma separated email addresses at project level. Project admin can add email addresses of associated parties or mailing list address to which he needs to send email notification for ticket change.

For this requirement, we studied around the data model but we didn't got the right place to store this information. Do we need to extend any entity for this or is there any best practice for this? This requirement is very useful in any project management application. We appreciate any help on this data modeling problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best practice is to use existing data model elements as they are available. Having a normalized data model involves more work in querying data, but also more flexibility in addressing a wide variety of requirements without changes to the data structures.

In this case with a joined query you can get a list of email addresses in a single query based on the project's workEffortId. If you are dealing with massive data and message volumes there are better solutions than denormalizing source data, but I doubt that's the case... unless you're dealing with more than thousands of projects and millions of messages per day the basic query and iterate approach will work just fine.

If you need to go beyond that the easiest approach with Moqui is to use a DataDocument and DataFeed to send updates on the fly to ElasticSearch, and then use it for your high volume queries and filtering (with arbitrarily complex filtering, etc requirements).

Your question is way too open to answer directly, data modeling is a complex topic and without good understanding of context and intended usage there are no good answers. In general it's best to start with a data model based on decades of experience and used in a large number of production systems. The Mantle UDM is one such model.

Comment: Thanks for your helpful guidance David. We are using **WorkEffortContactMech** for addressing this task. I will try to explain requirement again over here. We have a requirement in which we need to inform any changes in ticket into project management app to intended set of users and we wanted to avoid iterations through entity for getting email addresses of the intended parties. So we thought of storing all email addresses of users (comma separated) at project level so that there is no need of any iterations to get addresses. We were not sure which field in data model we should use.